# Return Identity Key from select statement in a stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure that selects all the records from a database.

```
Select * 
from dbo.Recods
where Active = 1;
```

but when I run this stored procedure, I do not get the identity key back, just the rest of the columns in the database.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What is your table definition `CREATE TABLE...` please?

Comment: *"when I run this store procedure"*: there is no stored procedure involved in your query. Please provide the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The query to create the table is:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tournaments] (
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
TournamentName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
EntryFee float,
Active int
);